# SQL Equivalent to `nameof` operator in C#, Java, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, nameof

Is there an equivalent to the `nameof` operator in languages like C#, Java, etc for any SQL database implementations, in particular SQL Server?

If not, is there an equivalent function that can be rolled that will pass back a string (`VARCHAR`, etc) of a given object (for example, `[dbo].[MyTable]`) which is passed to it?

Comment: can you give example of how would you use it in sql?

Comment: No there is no equivalent function. There is no way of passing a reference to an object to a function. You can't do `MyFunc([dbo].[MyTable])` or anything like that. You could only do `MyFunc('[dbo].[MyTable]')` and pass an opaque string. What is the motivation for wanting this?

Comment: The motivation is fairly irrelevant, but it had to do with the need to disambiguate several columns for the output with similar names from several tables from several databases which all have duplicated/similar data. We're doing lots of data cleanup right now across our department and it made me wonder if it was possible to speed up the process of writing tedious queries, and more generally if such a thing was possible. The question itself doesn't necessarily reflect the motivation anyway, and I was moreover curious if a `nameof` equivalent was even possible in any SQL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of an object, you can pass the ID.
You can get the ID from the name of the object.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
select object_name(object_id('my_table_name'))
```

Comment: I was looking to pass in a table/variable/etc and get back a string, more or less identical to how the `nameof` operator works. I'm just curious if it's even possible.